# OpenGL: Generating a single square with a Quad Strip

Tags: opengl, 3d, terrain-rendering

I am currently trying to create a terrain generation system (for my 3D game) with OpenGL 2.1.

The way I am doing it requires the creation of a massive 2D square that consists of multiple smaller squares. After the flat square is generated, the points are randomly offset in the y axis, making it into a 3D structure.

But I can't seem to figure out how to generate this using GL_QUAD_STRIP. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Thanks!

P.s. I know my method may not be the best, but I would like to get it to work anyway as it suits my game

Comment: Can I ask why do you need quad strips? They're deprecated. Just use simple triangles.

Comment: Oh ok. I was using quad strips because I thought would be easier to do the terrain generation (to me atleast).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about drawing a quad strip for each row in your grid of quads?

I guess it depends on how you're representing your data. One way could be to have a 2D array of 3D coordinates for the grid's vertices. To start, the Y component can be zero and then you can assign random Y values while maintaining the X and Z values intact. Then you would draw a GL_QUAD_STRIP using two rows of coordinates at a time from the 2D array: the first strip uses rows 0 and 1, the second strip uses rows 1 and 2 (row 1 is common to the first two strips) and so on... Does that fit your need?

Comment: I originally tried that, but I need all the squares in the grid to be connected, for the purpose of altering the y axis smoothly. But if you can specify a way to draw the quads while sharing the same points, that would be great!

Comment: I guess it depends on how you're representing your data. One way could be to have a 2D array of 3D coordinates for the grid's vertices. To start, the Y component can be zero and then you can assign random Y values while maintaining the X and Z values intact. Then you would draw a GL_QUAD_STRIP using two rows of coordinates at a time from the 2D array: the first strip uses rows 0 and 1, the second strip uses rows 1 and 2 (row 1 is common to the first two strips) and so on... Does that fit your need?

Comment: Yes! I was already doing something like this, but you helped point me in the exact direction. This is perfect! Put this in your current answer so others can see it and I will mark it as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey I'm glad that helped! I've pasted my comment into the answer so you can accept it. Thanks!